# How to add more partitions to Existing partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a Big table Which is having monthly Partitions From 01-2013 to 12-2016, I have not created partitions after December 2016.

SQL Server is using Last partition to Insert the data from December,2016.

Can someone help:

- Which is the best way to Extend the Partition and move the data of
  Last partition into Separate Partitions month wise?
- Create more partitions for future use?

I have a Clustered Index and 3 Non Clustered Index on the Table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this post from Dan Guzman - -https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/146952/60085